# Creating a generic function for objects of different classes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

How might I refactor this to get rid of all the if-else?

```
  def self.dispatches_for(object)
    scope = Dispatch.asc(:days)
    if object.class == Habit
      scope.where(:habit=>object).map{|d|d}
    elsif object.class == User
      scope.where(:coach=>object).map{|d|d}
    elsif object.class == Content
      scope.where(:content=>object).map{|d|d}
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def self.dispatches_for(object)
  klass = object.class.to_s.downcase.to_sym
  raise "unacceptable class" unless klass.in? [:habit, :coach, :content]
  scope = Dispatch.asc(:days)
  scope.where(klass=>object).map{|d|d}
end
```

Comment: Also, if you're using `ActiveRecord` or similar you can do `scope.where(klass=>object).to_a` instead of `map{|d|d}`.

Comment: @kardeiz, yes, nice point. I'm not sure what is the usage so I refactored the logic only.